# Measure bandwidth between two computer in a LAN

Tags: linux, windows, networking, bandwidth

Is there any way to measure precisely bandwidth between two computers in a LAN?

Comment: Search for "how do i measure lan bandwidth"

Comment: [5 Free Tools to Test and Benchmark Your Network Speed](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/network-benchmark-test-your-network-speed/)  :)

Comment: [How do you test the network speed betwen two boxes?](//askubuntu.com/q/7976)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[iPerf](https://iperf.fr/) is designed to do exactly that and it is cross-platform. Download the version for your OS. On one of the computers run `iperf -s` (this is the server) and on the other run `iperf -c <server hostname or IP>` (this is the client). Then wait for the results. There are many options to tweak the measuring. Check `iperf -h`for a complete list of options.

Comment: This was a useful reference for me on how to use iPerf: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/

Comment: On one computer run `iperf3 -s` then on the other computer run `iperf3 -c <destip>`.

Comment: Is there another tool that works better in Windows? I seem to be capping out around 13-14Gb when using this tool.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes I never had any issues with iPerf. Did you try both versions, i.e. iPerf2 and iPerf3?
In any case, there is another, apparently more modern solution here: https://github.com/udhos/goben
I have not tried it, but there are binaries for Windows on the release page as well.

Comment: The newer binaries ran a lot faster.